# What is the maximum thrust of the Starlink satellites?

Tags: spacex, thrust, starlink

As in the title, what is the maximum thrust (in N) that the satellites of the Starlink constellation can achieve? I read that they use Hall-effect thrusters, but I couldn't find a specification of the maximum thrusting force.

Comment: I think it should be described in SpaceX filing for authorization to deploy Starlink (FCC filing). The reason is that all constellations filed for operation in the US market must provide an analysis for debris generation mitigation (therefore including capability to maneuver and capability to actively dispose at end-of-life).

Comment: Maximum is unknown, but we can determine a minimum. They *all* change their orbital height at the same rate of 300km->500km in 30 days.(up or down, same slope). That's 114m/s of deltav, call it 134.5m/s with the continuous thrust vs impulse inefficiency. 134.5m/s on a 260kg craft over 30 days is 0.0135N

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking
You can multiply that number by 2, roughly - running a 500W ion thruster during night would be quite unlikely.

Comment: @asdfex, not sure. The communication payload requires large power (perhaps largest), so battery capability must be embarked for this function at "night". During orbit elevation, the com payload is not used.

Comment: @NgPh that's (potentially) a good point; they could use most of the available power during the non-operational elevation period. As an aside, I wonder if the thruster is variable power, or if it is only full thrust or off when doing station keeping and altitude maintenance (same thing I guess). So I've just asked [Do operational Starlink satellites run their ion engines at night on batteries? And if so, do they have hi/low settings?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55959/12102)

Comment: Unfortunately, the granularity of the orbital plots is way too coarse to determine if they are actually thrusting continuously or only during sunlight. I *think* the non-deviation between perigee and apogee show this, but who really knows. It is pertinent to the Question, but not to my partial comment-answer with regards to minimum. Yes we could maybe(likely?) double that thrust figure, but that requires assumptions be made. Unverifiable assumptions.

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking can you show how you got these numbers? Any links?